# WCSession: Best way of using transferUserInfo or sendMessage?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, wcsession

I'm currently sending a list of users in form of an array of dictionaries using transferUserInfo().

I come to think that I really don't make use of the FIFO behavior that the UserInfo transfer provides to me.

So I come to think if I could send my data with sendMessage() instead.

Will it do any different of how much data each background transfer method can contain?

Or is it fine using transferUserInfo() without using its FIFO behavior???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer depends on the nature of how you are sending data.

If you are requesting data from your watch and then replying with the data from the phone then you should use sendMessage() with a reply handler.

If you are sending data from the phone without being prompted by the watch you should use transferUserInfo() because it is allowed to transfer in the background. sendMessage() only fires when the apple watch is in foreground.